# jquery data tables - Server-side processing not working as expected

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have got a JSON object that I receive from a php file,the JSON object is created as per the specified format.But I get the 
the warning UNRESPONSIVE SCRIPT.I have got over 50,000 records and it loads every record instead of the 20 records I specified in the iDisplayLength parameter.
I know Im doing something wrong,please help.

The JSON Object :

```
{
    "iTotalRecords":"52000",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords":"52000",
    "sEcho":0,
    "aaData":[
        {"itemID":"13901","itemName":"Item 1","itemModel":"Model 1","Price":"20"},
        {"itemID":"13902","itemName":"Item 2","itemModel":"Model 2","Price":"30"},
        {"itemID":"13903","itemName":"Item 3","itemModel":"Model 3","Price":"50"},
        {"itemID":"13904","itemName":"Item 4","itemModel":"Model 4","Price":"60"},
        {"itemID":"13905","itemName":"Item 5","itemModel":"Model 5","Price":"20"},
        ................
    ]
}    

$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#tbItems').dataTable( {
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "sAjaxSource": "getItems",
                        "aoColumns": [
                          { "sTitle": "itemID",  "mDataProp": "itemID" },
                          { "sTitle": "itemName",  "mDataProp": "itemName" },
                          { "sTitle": "itemModel", "mDataProp": "itemModel" },
                          { "sTitle": "itemPrice",  "mDataProp": "itemPrice" }
                        ],
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "iDisplayLength": 20,
                        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you show us your server side code?

Comment: You are getting the `unresponsive script` notice from the browser, right?  Have you tried sending less than 50k records and to let the the user page through results?

Comment: @DuaneGran yea Im getting the unresponsive script from the browser.No I have not tried sending less than 50k.What do you mean my user page through results? Sorry didnt get that bit

Comment: @manraj82 you are asking the browser to parse 50k records in JSON format.  This is a lot of data to process.  Start by passing back only 1,000 records and see if it runs quickly.  Now change your back end to deliver only 1k and give the user next/prev buttons to page through the results and a good search box to find records in the entire 50k set.

Comment: Check ShadowScripter's answer. To elaborate, your script is setting server-side, but not actually doing server-side processing. In your current example, despite setting bServerSide to true, you're actually just using DataTables with an Ajax source, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server can only pass a certain amount of data through a request.

Essentially, what datatables is doing, is, even though you define a display parameter, it will still fetch *all* the data from your source and then process it.

Datatables fetches the data and then processes everything and puts it in an internal array. I can only imagine how much space it would take up after only a couple of hundred rows.

In any case, the `bServerSide` boolean notifies datatables that you're going to handle and process everything yourself and then feed back what you want. You should read up on the documentation and examples available at [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/).

You should pay close attention to how they do the server side processing since it is perfect for your scenario where you have a huge dataset to work with.

- [iDeferLoading](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html) could be used if you knew exactly how many rows your initial dataset has
- [Server side setup](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) (Scroll down to "Server-side (PHP) code") & [Datatables server-side processing pipeline](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)

The last one shows a complete reference to how to manage large datasets and how to do the paging, and pretty much everything, on the server side, effectively saving up loads of processing time for datatables.

Your problem is that you're returning everything but forgetting to filter the data to only include the rows on the current "page". This is all done on the *server-side*, hence the variable name.

Comment: This is mostly correct. iDeferLoading is used when the first page of the DataTable is rendered in the HTML view rather than being fetched from the server; in other words, it's not really about knowing how many rows the dataset has, but whether you want the rendered HTML to contain that first page or whether the data will get retrieved from the server after the HTML renders.

Comment: @shadowscripter thanks for your answer,made more sense when you explained it to me